# Override publish folder (url) of publish profile during the build pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, msbuild, pubxml

We have one ASP.Net solution with several projects.  each project have `build.pubxml` with unique folder path.

For example:

In project `Test` we have this line inside the `build.pubxml`:

```
<publishUrl>C:\publish\SolutionName\Test</publishUrl>
```

In project `Exam` we have this line inside the `build.pubxml`:

```
<publishUrl>C:\publish\SolutionName\Exam</publishUrl>
```

In the build pipeline (in TFS) with have MSBuild step with this argument:

```
/p:PublishProfile=build.pubxml
```

After the build we got 2 folders - `Test` and `Exam` in `C:\publish\SolutionName`.

So far so good.

The problem is we have few branches, and we want to separate the publish folder for each branch, so we added `.pubxml` for each branch and in the build pipeline we specified the correct one. but is make are a lot of work on each new branch created and can cause mistakes.

We tried to pass the `/p:publishUrl=C:\publish\BranchName` in the MSBuild but then we got a one folder with all the content of `Test` and `Exam` and not two folders.

The idea is to have only **one** `.pubxml` file for each project with a parameter and pass the value in the pipeline, for example:

```
<publishUrl>C:\publish\$(Parameter)\Test</publishUrl>
```

And in the build we will pass the parameter according to the branch.

It is possible to do something like this?

Comment: I assume you're using the VS build task which calls msbuild to do the build and deploy. And msbuild can accept properties in command-line even though those properties are not defined in csproj, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is possible to do something like this?

The answer is Yes. Since msbuild accepts [Global Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties) in command-line. If we define one Property in `build.pubxml` like `<publishUrl>C:\PublishFolders\$(BranchID)\xxx(Test,Exam...)</publishUrl>`, then we can simply pass the value in msbuild arguments like this:

[image]

Then we'll get `Test` and `Exam` folders under `C:\PublishFolders\NewTest`. Also we can choose to pass the pipeline predefined variables to the command like: `/p:BranchID=$(Build.SourceBranch)`...

This works for build in local machine, tfs and Azure Devops pipeline. Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Thank you @Lance, I will check it soon and I will update :)

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to let me know if there's any update :)